Reading all links from a tab in a Chrome (v3) extension using context menu
I've spent hours looking at solutions online but the ones I've found are either not applicable or just don't seem to be working for me. I've looked at the documentation as well and can't see what I'm missing.
I am coding a chrome extension and I want the user to be able to right-click anywhere on a particular website and have the system return all links on that page.
Here are my bits of code:
manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Test Chrome Extension",
  "description": "Testing access to the DOM using a v3 
manifest Chrome extension.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "service_worker" : "background.js"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "activeTab",
    "notifications"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["https://stackoverflow.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],

  "host_permissions": [
    "https://stackoverflow.com/*"
  ]

}

background.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

  chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'stacko',
    title: 'Read Dom from Stackoverflow.com',
    type: 'normal',
    contexts: ['all'],
    targetUrlPatterns: ['https://stackoverflow.com/*']
  });
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener((tab, info) => 
{
  if (info.menuItemId === "stacko") {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { action: 
"getDOM" });
    }
});

content.js:
var array = [];
var links = document.links;
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    array.push(links[i].href);
}
console.log(links);

Initially I didn't realise the background worker couldn't access the DOM but read a bit on context scripts but I can't seem to figure out where it's referenced or fired off.


(tab, info) should be (info, tab). See the documentation.

Content scripts in Chrome won't run automatically after the extension is installed or updated or reloaded. Although you can inject them explicitly, it's wasteful to inject scripts unconditionally.
A better solution is to inject on demand.


chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(async (info, tab) => {
  if (info.menuItemId === 'stacko') {
    const [{result}] = await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: {tabId: tab.id},
      func: getDOM,
    });
    console.log(result); // in background console
  }
});

function getDOM() {
  const array = Array.from(document.links, a => a.href);
  console.log(array); // in website console
  return array;
}

Changes to manifest.json:

Add "scripting" to "permissions".
Remove content_scripts, host_permissions, content.js.

